# Creating huge number of samplers under thread group in Jmeter

Tags: http, jmeter

I have a requirement where I need to send HTTP requests to large number of small files (probably many 100 thousands) and I am trying to find an efficient way to create a large nuumber of HTTP Samplers under a thread group.

Is there a way to automate this so that I can create a request in such a way that

http:///folder[index]/file[index]

index can vary from 0..500000

I would like to pump the traffic with GETs on this request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) is something which can help you in implementing your scenario.

If that `index` bit can be a random value in range from zero to 500000 amend your request as follows to use [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function:

```
http://folder${__Random(0,500000,)}/file${__Random(0,500000,)}
```

If you want the index to be consecutive, i.e.

- 1st request - index=1
- 2nd request - index=2
- etc.

Then [__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function is your friend and path stanza should be something like:

```
http://folder${__counter(,)}/file${__counter(,)}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more details on the most popular JMeter functions.